# Creating a dynamic tooltip in Angular using typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, tooltip

I'm working on creating a dynamic tooltip for a stacked column chart (amcharts 4) in my angular application. Below is what I currently have:

```
if (keys[i] == "element1") {
   series.columns.template.tooltipText = this tooltip
   ? this.tooltip
   : "[#fff font-size: 14px]{name}: [#fff font-size: 14px]{valueY} [/n][/n] [#fff font-size: 14px] ({valueY.totalPercent.formatNumber('#.00')}%) [/n] [#fff font-size: 12px]{additional}";
} else {
   series.columns.template.tooltipText = this tooltip
   ? this.tooltip
   : "[#fff font-size: 14px]{name}: [#fff font-size: 14px]{valueY} [/n] [#fff font-size: 12px]{additional}";


//additional code
series.name = keys[i];
series.datafields.valueY = string(keys[i]);
series.datafields.valueYShow = "totalPercent";
```

What I would like to happen is have a condition for the above if else statement to be initiated. For example I would only like element1's tooltip to be changed if it's percent is below '0.05%'.

I tried adding a simple condition in the if statement like below which did not work.

```
if (keys[i] == "element1" && series.datafields.valueYShow < "0.05")
```

I'm wondering if there's an easy way to do this with my existing code, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your condition won’t work like that because there is no “smaller then a string” I guess? You need numbers to do that?

Comment: Thanks for the response MikeOne, do you know a way I could convert the string to a number within this query?

Comment: You can try to parseFloat them?